# How to inclue a drop down list into a Tapestry3 Contrib:Table component?

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, tapestry

I'm working with the Tapestry3 and Contrib:Table library. I want to include a dropdown list into each row of a table component.
The code may looks like the below:

```
<table jwcid="table@contrib:Table" width="90%"
    source="..."
    columns="..."/>
<span jwcid="selectColumnHeader@Block"><span jwcid="selectPayementMehtod"></span></span>
```

If someone can shed some light on this, that will be very appreiciated!

Comment: why are you using tapestry 3?

Comment: I'm working on a legacy project(it started in 2005), I have to use the Tapestry3. Or if you can provide a sample using any tapestry version. That will be also very helpful for me. Thanks again.